# How can i get the url using C# windows application?

Tags: c#, http, ip, windows, sharppcap

How can i get the url sent from my pc, i can get the ip of the sites that i've visited using [SharpPcap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET).

I wonder if there's a way to get the http message from the IP packet, or an easier wat to just get the url.

Comment: can you please state what problem and or issues you are currently having  with the code that you have posted..? are you getting any errors..? if so post the errors.. edit your question and explain what the problem is wit the current code..

Comment: There is NO errors with the code, i'm just showing the way that i got the ip with it.

Comment: what i need is to get the url, i don't know how to get it

Comment: The URL? As in, the URL associated with the packet that you received? Not that familiar with networking, but I think you might need a reverse DNS lookup. I don't know how or if it's possible to do that with .NET, sorry.